# If there is only One Eternal Spirit, and the Father is a Spirit, who/what is the Holy Spirit of God?

Tags: pneumatology, spirit, trinity, god-the-father

Jesus tells the woman at the well to worship the Father in Spirit and Truth.

> John 4:23-24
> King James Version
> 23 But the hour cometh, and now is, when the true worshippers shall worship the Father in spirit and in truth: for the Father seeketh such to worship him.
> 24 God is a Spirit: and they that worship him must worship him in spirit and in truth.

In this passage we see the only begotten Son of YHWH, once again declaring his God to be the Father(and is a Spirit), who seeks worship as the one true God.

Paul makes it clear that there is 1 Spirit.

> Eph4:4 There is one body, and one Spirit, even as ye are called in one hope of your calling;
> 5 One Lord, one faith, one baptism,
> 6 One God and Father of all, who is above all, and through all, and in you all.

If there is 1 (eternal)Spirit and 1 God and Father of all, who IS also Spirit....
then, who or what is the Holy Spirit of God?

Comment: Can someone point me to a place online or in real life where the brethren are not afraid of the pursuit of Truth?  What a stale, dead place this is where the law is used to silence those who seek answers.  Not much has changed.  And for those who don't quite understand past the milk.... Jesus was thee greatest heretic by definition.  Shalom.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to Jesus there was two cherubim that covered the mercy seat of gold, the three pieces were overlaid with gold making them of one piece, Father Yahweh would appear in the midst of those three in the form of smoke.[1]

One of the covering cherub wanted to have more than what he had so God cast him as profane from the mountain of God. This was satan.[2]

Sometime during this satan retaliated by deceiving Eve. They covered themselves in fig leaves (a picture of angel wings). Satan’s way of telling God, “You still need me.”[3]

God responds by killing an animal and using it to clothe Adam and Eve, for the wages of sin is death.[4]

At this point the throne of God is no longer adequately covered, and mankind is separated from God.

The other cherub, being in the form of God, makes Himself a little lower than the angels and dies a criminal death on the cross, thus fulfilling God’s requirement for sin. Now He sits on the throne at the right hand of the Father and all creation worships Him.[5]

So what of the devil who wanted to be like God, an all consuming fire that leads us and guides us.

“For we will surely die and become like water spilled on the ground, which cannot be gathered up again. Yet God does not take away a life; but He devises means, so that His banished ones are not expelled from Him.”
(‭‭II Samuel‬ ‭14:14‬ ‭NKJV‬‬)

Only ones cast into a lake of fire is the devil, His angels, and anyone not written in the book of life.[6]

God causes everything to work for good and in the throne room in Revelation, cherubim are still there.[7]

Perhaps God allows their “wisdom” to guide us until we meet the Real.[8]

Explains why we see now only partially, also the one Jesus testified of having fallen from heaven was Satan. Who was the ruler of the world.[9]

Almost like at the cross God said “get out of His seat” to the devil and now Jesus sits while he works.

References for this are:

1. Exodus 25:17-22
2. Isaiah 14:12-15, Ezekiel 28:13-17
3. Genesis 3:6-7, 14
4. Genesis 3:21, Romans 6:23
5. Philippians 2:5-11
6. Revelation 20:10,14-15, Romans 8:28
7. Revelation chapter 4
8. Genesis 3:1
9. 1 Corinthians 13:12, Luke 10:18, John 12:31

---

“The entirety of Your word is truth, And every one of Your righteous judgments endures forever.”
(‭‭Psalms‬ ‭119:160‬ ‭NKJV‬‬)

“Many, O Lord my God, are Your wonderful works Which You have done; And Your thoughts toward us Cannot be recounted to You in order; If I would declare and speak of them, They are more than can be numbered.”
‭‭(Psalms‬ ‭40:5‬ ‭NKJV‬‬)

The truth is all in the Word, sometimes it just isn’t in order. That’s what happens when someone is struck on the head that hard, but remember He was bruised for our transgressions.

Pattern for this would be God speaking through the mouth of a donkey